# Редирект при помощи nginx, apache или html

Tags: html, apache, nginx

Есть два сайта, один с контентом, а второй с лендингом.

Нужно мгновенно перенаправлять юзера с content.domain.com на domain.com

сервер ubuntu с apache и nginx

каким образом можно сделать мгновенный редирект, но с условием, что доступ к 
content.domain.com/folder и content.domain.com/dashboard будет возможен без редиректа?

я попытался сделать редирект при помощи конфига nginx, ввел в раздел server {}

```
 server_name  www.content.domain.com;
 rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
```

и после этого утратил возможность перейти по ссылке content.domain.com/dashboard и т.д.

Comment: а в каком случае должно срабатывать перенаправление?

Comment: @alexander-barakin

когда юзер переходит по адресу content.domain.com или www.content.domain.com его нужно перебросить на domain.com

Comment: т.е., если *url* равен `/`. и с какими же трудностями вы столкнулись при реализации? уточните их, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перенаправлять вам надо при запросе `/`, т.е. при обращении к корню сайта, но при любом ином *url* — перенаправления не делать.

значит, так и напишите в соответствующей директиве:

```
rewrite ^/$ http://domain.com permanent;
```